# Trying to strip a list of punctuation for each word - end up removing all punctuation

Tags: python, strip

I am new to Python and am having trouble understanding why I'm getting certain errors or things aren't working the way that I hoped it would.

One thing I'm trying to do is to replace trailing given punctuation from all the words in a sentence. This is what I have:

`def beautify_sentence(sentence, punctuation):
    """Returns a sentence that removes all the specified trailing punctuation from 
    words."""
    sentence = [words.strip(punctuation) for words in sentence]
    return "".join(sentence)`

Input:

```
beautify_sentence("?hello !mango! and, ban,ana yum apple!", "?!,")
```

Output:

```
'hello mango and banana yum apple'
```

But I want:

```
"hello mango and ban,ana yum apple"
```

Can someone explain to me why strip() is doing this and what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: The point is *trailing*, you'll need a regular expression.

Comment: When you do this:  for words in sentence, it will split each LETTERS in the sentence rather than WORDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you are doing is iterating over every character in the sentence and then stripping the punctuation marks from that character instead *you have to iterate over the words in the sentence and then strip the punctuation marks from the beginning and ending of these words.*

Use:

```
def beautify_sentence(sentence, punctuation):
    """Returns a sentence that removes all the specified trailing punctuation from 
    words."""
    sentence = [word.strip(punctuation) for word in sentence.split()]
    return " ".join(sentence)
```

Calling the function:

```
beautify_sentence("?hello !mango! and, ban,ana yum apple!", "?!,")
```

This returns:

```
hello mango and ban,ana yum apple
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I kind of understand it. I'm still trying to wrap my brain around Python. 
Although, why does it iterate over all the characters if i leave it as sentence instead of sentence.split()?

Comment: sentence is string and it is a list of characters, so doing a loop thru a list of chars will be each letter in the list (sentence)

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting your sentence by letters, so please split your sentence by space before you remove the leading/trailing chars. Then return the sentence by joining the words delimited by space.

```
NEW:
    sentence = [words.strip(punctuation) for words in sentence.split()]
    return " ".join(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
(?:(?<!\w)[?!,])|(?:[?!,](?!\w))
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/aUxi6A/1).

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'(?:(?<!\w)[?!,])|(?:[?!,](?!\w))')

string = rx.sub('', "?hello !mango! and, ban,ana yum apple!")
print(string)
# hello mango and ban,ana yum apple
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. :) I don't think I can use rx because it isn't something that we have been taught yet.